# Loading extensions into SQLite at COMPILE TIME

Tags: sqlite

Similar to how you can integrate the SQLite JSON1 extension into the app at **compile-time** with `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1`, how do I load an extension of my own at compile-time, without having to `.load my-extension` in the SQLite shell?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your extension C code file into some SQLite checkout, and in `src/shell.c.in`, just put in `INCLUDE <path>` where `<path>` is the path to your extension C code. Hopefully, it's all in one file.

[image]